# How often does Stack Exchange get a platform and technology stack review?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, architecture

I was curious to know how often the SE development team evaluate the current technology stack that powers the sites and what would constitute a good enough reason to migrate?

For example, jQuery was last updated in 2016, the technology stack was updated to WISC, at some point there was a switch to Dapper, and so on. What drove those changes and what else have you evaluated, but passed on?

Comment: The blog from Nick Craver could serve as an answer: https://nickcraver.com/blog/archive/ as well as his Twitter feed ...